# while loop keep printing and repeating, what is wrong with my getch?

Tags: c, while-loop, getch

i am trying to make the loop stop after typing y/n, but it just returning printing and asking for a char. what is wrong here?

code:

```
char con='r';

while(con != 'n' || con != 'y')
{
    printf("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
    con=getch();
}
```

Comment: `while(con != 'n' || con != 'y')` -->> `while(con != 'n' && con != 'y')` for a start ...

Comment: oh oops thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Note your while condition; One of the two conditions is always true, therefore the while condition is always true.

Change it to:

```
while (con != 'n' && con != 'y')
```